# PHP/MySQL Select Statement

Tags: php, mysql

This one's probably easy:

I have two variables:

```
$sender_id
$receiver_id
```

Those ID's are stored and assigned to a user in tblusers.  I have no problem selecting one-at-a-time:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblusers WHERE usrID='$receiverID'") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
{
echo $row['usrFirstName'];
echo $row['usrLastName'];
}
```

However, how would I select both rows (one for senderID and receiverID) so that I can gain access to further information on both those users.  Sort of like a "SELECT within a SELECT".

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tblusers WHERE usrID='$receiverID' or usrID='$sender_id'
```

EDIT: clarification

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
{
    if($row['usrID'] == $receiverID) {
        echo "Receiver: " . $row['usrFirstName'] . " " . $row['usrLastName'];
    } else {
        echo "Sender: " . $row['usrFirstName'] . " " . $row['usrLastName'];
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  So, in my "while" statement, how would I differentiate between the $senderID and $receiverID, if I wanted to refer to one specifically.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to differentiate which is the receiver and which is the sender:

```
select
    'Receiver' as UserType,
    *
from
    users
where
    usrid = $receiver_id
union all
select
    'Sender' as UserType,
    *
from
    users
where
    usrid = $sender_id
```

This will return:

```
UserType  |  UsrID  |  Name
Receiver  |   23    |  John Smith
Sender    |   42    |  Adam Douglas
```

Of course, with two rows, you can always just compare the ID's to figure that out, too. This is mainly to make scaling easier if you have a larger result set than just two rows.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM tblusers WHERE usrID IN ($receiverID, sender_id)